# Pointer-events without the pass-through effect

Tags: css

I am trying to code a DIV that

- Does not react to pointer events(clicks)
- Does NOT allow the clicks to target the element behind it.

**Is there such a thing in CSS?**

Obviously `pointer-events:none`, satisfies the 1st parameter but not the 2nd.

Comment: so looks like you can just place some layer on top of the div, that on-top layer will prevent all the mouse events from going down to the DIV and the elements behind.

Comment: yeah I figured I could hack my way around that way. I am just wondering if there's a more elegant ''native'' solution to this.

Comment: Probably not. It would break the principles of CSS if one element could influence another unrelated element.